# Javascript promises giving TypeError function is undefined

Tags: javascript, promise, typeerror

The code below gives a correct result.
But if *then(callback('sum'))* is removed from the promise *sumOfPromises* and added to the call to *sumOfPromises* (like this : *sumOfPromises().then(callback('sum'))*) then I get *TypeError: sumOfPromises(...) is undefined*. 
There is someting wrong in *sumOfPromises* that I cannot understand.

```html
<pre>P_1 is : <span id=p_1>p_1</span></pre>
<pre>P_2 is : <span id=p_2>p_2</span></pre>
<pre>Sum is : <span id=sum>sum</span></pre>

<script>
 promise_1().then(callback('p_1'));
 promise_2().then(callback('p_2'));
 sumOfPromises(); // sumOfPromises().then(callback('sum')); gives TypeError: sumOfPromises(...) is undefined (see below)

 function callback(tag) {
     const result = obj => {
  let e = document.getElementById(tag);
  e.innerHTML = obj;
     };
     return result
 }

 function sumOfPromises() {
     const promises = [promise_1(), promise_2()];
     
     Promise.all(promises).then(function (data) {
  return sumOfData(data)
     }).then(callback('sum')); // then moved to top gives TypeError: sumOfPromises(...) is undefined (see upper)
 }
 
 function sumOfData(data) {
     const [p_1, p_2] = data;
     console.log('sumOfData input p_1 '+p_1);
     console.log('sumOfData input p_2 '+p_2);
     
     return new Promise ( (resolve) => {
  var result = p_1 + p_2;
  console.log('sumOfData result '+result);
  resolve(result)
     });
 } 

 function promise_1() {
     return new Promise((resolve) => {
  const value = Math.random();
  console.log('promise_1 value '+value);
  resolve(value);
     })
 }

 function promise_2() {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const value = - Math.random();
  console.log('promise_2 value '+value);
  resolve(value);
     })
 }

</script>
```

Comment: The promise is not being returned from `sumOfData` and therefore the function returns `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning anything in `sumOfPromises`, so you can´t attach callbacks to it since its `undefined`:

```
 function sumOfPromises() {
     const promises = [promise_1(), promise_2()];

     return Promise.all(promises).then(function (data) { // Add 'return' here
       return sumOfData(data)
     }).then(callback('sum'));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return promise from sumOfPromises. Since in your code you don't have a return statement in sumOfPromises javaScript implicitly return undefined so you end up with a call like this

```
undefined.then(callback('sum'));  // which is an error
```

---

```html
<pre>P_1 is : <span id=p_1>p_1</span></pre>
<pre>P_2 is : <span id=p_2>p_2</span></pre>
<pre>Sum is : <span id=sum>sum</span></pre>

<script>
 promise_1().then(callback('p_1'));
 promise_2().then(callback('p_2'));
 sumOfPromises().then(callback('sum'));
 
 function callback(tag) {
     const result = obj => {
  let e = document.getElementById(tag);
  e.innerHTML = obj;
     };
     return result
 }

 function sumOfPromises() {
     const promises = [promise_1(), promise_2()];
     
     return Promise.all(promises).then(function (data) {
  return sumOfData(data)
     }) 
 }
 
 function sumOfData(data) {
     const [p_1, p_2] = data;
     console.log('sumOfData input p_1 '+p_1);
     console.log('sumOfData input p_2 '+p_2);
     
     return new Promise ( (resolve) => {
  var result = p_1 + p_2;
  console.log('sumOfData result '+result);
  resolve(result)
     });
 } 

 function promise_1() {
     return new Promise((resolve) => {
  const value = Math.random();
  console.log('promise_1 value '+value);
  resolve(value);
     })
 }

 function promise_2() {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const value = - Math.random();
  console.log('promise_2 value '+value);
  resolve(value);
     })
 }

</script>
```